# Fetching shipping method options

Tags: shipping

How can I fetch the options or details of the **shipping method** configured in the admin side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that just like you get any config value:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('PATH GOES HERE');
```

In you case it will be

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/[shipping_method_code]/[field_name]');
```

Replace '[shipping_method_code]' and '[field_name]' with the appropriate values.

**[EDIT]**
as @nevvermind said in the comments below.
If you have the shiping method model instance you can use:

```
$model->getConfigData('[field_name]');
```

take a look at how `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract::getConfigData` works.

Comment: For completeness' sake: and `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract::getConfigData/getConfigFlag('[field_name]')`.

Comment: @nevvermind. Right. That would work to. I will add it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Than you so much, I'm still new to magento so I had a hard time configuring these stuffs. But this already answered my question ^_^